# is there a way to manage DNS without being a sysadmin?

Tags: linux

I had a server at a linode, and they provided a great interface to manage DNS.  I have my domain registered at verisign, and just pointed to ns.linode.com and went from there.

Now, I have a box at a colocation facility that let me put a box in a rack, but they do not provide DNS management nor have any such interface to do that.

So, I am sort of stuck - I need to manage DNS (and the demands are quite modest) but not sure of how to do so.  Anyone have any words to offer for this situation?  Should I try and set up my own DNS server on my box?  Is it that hard to do that?

TIA!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using verisign's domain registration service (man, that's expensive), I guess you can afford their [managed dns service](http://www.verisigninc.com/DNS) as well.

Otherwise, there are tons of [other](https://dnsimple.com/) [alternatives](http://www.loaddns.com/). The google keyword is "hosted dns" / "managed dns".

Comment: well, the domain I registered was back in 30-may-1995 when there were not as many alternatives as network solutions.  however, my domain is set to expire on 29-may-2012 so I could always re-up with someone else.  any suggestions on where to move my domain?  maybe I could move it somewhere that *also* lets me manage DNS?  I appreciate your answer thank you.

Comment: ok I guess your right.  for a one year renewal, netsol wants $37.99 that sounds high to me.  Is moving a domain to another registrar very hard to do?

Comment: DNSimple.com ROCKS !  solid tip there, thanks.  Run, don't walk, to DNSimple.com !

Answer (score 2):

There are a few options:

1. Using registrar's DNS service. Many registrars provide DNS service for free, not sure if Verisign has it or not but GoDaddy as well as many others do. It might be the cheapest option (even with domain transfer) but reliability of such service can be an issue though.
2. Using third-party DNS providers. There are a lot of companies providing DNS hosting with and without additional services such as Geo-DNS etc. Amazon Web Services now offers Route 53 as their DNS solution, which might also be an option for you.
3. Hosting your own DNS server. Configuring a DNS zone in BIND (by far the most popular choice of DNS server on linux) certainly isn't terribly difficult and can be done by most reasonably competent linux admins or even advanced users.

Comment: thanks Rock!  I'm actually at NetSol, which I think was bought by Verisign but I could be wrong.  I will investigate their DNS hosting, and also 3rd party and go from there.

Comment: +1 for Amazon Route53. Great service. Nicest DNS admin interface I've come across.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at Directi. They are leading domain name registrar. They also provide Managed DNS service on affordable prices.

Comment: If you're joining ServerFault to shill a site, don't.

Comment: Sorry, I am not trying to shill. Actually, I have many domain names registered with Directi, and that is why I have referred them.